# Conditionally changing values of a categorical survey response column in a data frame

Tags: r, object

trying to create an object that merges some categories in a variable

```
background <- NULL

data$y11[data$y11 == "English/Welsh/Scottish/Northern Irish/British"] <-"White"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Gypsy or Irish Traveller"] <-"White"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Any other White background, please describe"] <-"White"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Irish"] <-"White"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Any other Mixed/Multiple ethnic background, please describe"] <-"Mixed"

data$y11[data$y11 == "White and Asian "] <-"Mixed"

data$y11[data$y11 == "White and Black African "] <-"Mixed"

data$y11[data$y11 == "White and Black Caribbean"] <-"Mixed"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Any other Asian background, please describe"] <-"Asian"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Bangladeshi"] <-"Asian"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Chinese"] <-"Asian"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Indian"] <-"Asian"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Pakistani"] <-"Asian"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Arab"] <-"Arab & Other"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Any other ethnic group, please describ"] <-"Arab & Other"

data$y11[data$y11 == "African"] <-"Black"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Any other Black/African/Caribbean background, please describe"] <-"Black"

data$y11[data$y11 == "Caribbean"] <-"Black"
```

but i keep warning messages about "invalid factor level, NA generated"

pls help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It could be helpful to have your data, also a part of them, and a desired output.

Comment: Do you absolutely not want to create a new variable with the recodes?  Because basically what the error message is telling you is that you had a nominal (also known as categorical) variable with a defined set of attributes and now you are trying to create a new variable with a different set of attributes.  Two options not mentioned below are to use the forcats package or to use a hash.

Comment: yea i would like to create a new variable with the recodes ideally, now im not getting the error but im still getting old categories in the new variable that i dont want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your variables are factors. You can get around this in one of two ways:

1. Change all factors to characters using:

   `data$y11 <- as.character(data$y11)`
2. Add the new level that you want to the existing factor levels using:

   `levels(data$y11) <- c(levels(data$y11), "White", "Black", ...)`

Let me know if this doesn't make sense

Also, just in case you're new to R, you don't need to spread all the lines out like that. You can clump the race groups together, something like this:

```
 data$y11[data$y11 %in% c("English/Welsh/Scottish/Northern Irish/British",
                          "Gypsy or Irish Traveller",
                          "Any other White background, please describe",
                          "Irish")] <-"White"

 data$y11[data$y11 %in% c("Any other Mixed/Multiple ethnic background, please describe",
                          "White and Asian ",
                          "White and Black African ",
                          "White and Black Caribbean")] <-"Mixed"

 data$y11[data$y11 %in% c("Any other Asian background, please describe",
                          "Bangladeshi",
                          "Chinese",
                          "Indian",
                          "Pakistani")] <-"Asian"

 data$y11[data$y11 %in% c("Arab",
                          "Any other ethnic group, please describ")] <-"Arab & Other"

 data$y11[data$y11 %in% c("African",
                          "Any other Black/African/Caribbean background, please describe",
                          "Caribbean"] <-"Black"
```

Or there are plenty of other ways, like using the `|` (or) operator so you don't have to write each line out individually.

Comment: thank u so much! i'm no longer getting the error. but now when i use the table function to see the variable its coming up with the other categories in the variable that i dont want .i want it to be recoded to only "white" "mixed" "Asian" "arab & other" and "black" , does that make sense?? sorry if its realy obvious im new at r :)

Comment: try this: `table(data$y11[data$y11 %in% c("White", "Black", "Mixed", "Asian", "Arab & Other")]`. That should limit table to only include the frequency of those options. Let me know if I've misunderstood

Comment: I get that but what I want is to recode the variable so it only has those categories. Because I’m gonna use it in graphs and calculations I need it to be only those categories? I don’t get why the other ones are coming up since I’ve used code to overwrite them?? Thank u so much

Comment: If the variable is still a factor then the old values are still available factor levels, which is why they may show up. It is very difficult to help with this as we have no sample of our data so can't actually reproduce anything you say though

Comment: Is there a way to only have the new values in the new variable though? I don’t want the older ones to show up. And it’s weird because only some of the old ones are showing up even though I’ve tried to overwrite them to fit into the new categories?

Comment: is it still a factor variable? If so, just do `levels(data$y11) <- c(...)` where `...` is all the list of levels you want. If it's a character then I'm not sure what you mean without data

Comment: I did what you said and it’s a character variable. What I mean is some of the new categories (“white”, “black”,etc) have worked and show up when I put table(). But 2 old ones that I wanted to have merged into the new ones are still showing up and idk why bc I did what you said above? It’s just the “white and Asian” and “white and black African” that are still coming up instead of having gone into “mixed”. Does that make sense? Thanks again

Comment: Then they must still exist in the variable, as in you havent replaced them. R is case sensitive so maybe they didn't get replaced as they wer/wern't capitalised like the others

Comment: I know and I copy pasted it directly to avoid that! And it’s weird because it’s only 2 of the categories, all the other ones worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that you didn't use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you read in your data (likely with `read.csv`). So you should add that to the `read.csv` call.

There is also a better way to do what you're doing. One approach is to create a "lookup" or "translation" table from one category to the other and then use `merge` from base R or `left_join` from the "tidyverse" to automagically do the replacement for you without having all those conditional assignments.

We'll make the translation table:

```
data.frame(
  answer = c(
    "African", "Any other Asian background, please describe",
    "Any other Black/African/Caribbean background, please describe",
    "Any other ethnic group, please describ",
    "Any other Mixed/Multiple ethnic background, please describe",
    "Any other White background, please describe", "Arab", "Bangladeshi",
    "Caribbean", "Chinese", "English/Welsh/Scottish/Northern Irish/British",
    "Gypsy or Irish Traveller", "Indian", "Irish", "Pakistani", "White and Asian ",
    "White and Black African ", "White and Black Caribbean"
  ),
  subst = c(
    "Black", "Asian", "Black", "Arab & Other", "Mixed", "White",
    "Arab & Other", "Asian", "Black", "Asian", "White", "White", "Asian",
    "White", "Asian", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> trans_tbl
```

Now we'll simulate some data (I'm using `dat` vs `data` as the variable name since using `data` will eventually cause you pain some day since it's an R function name):

```
set.seed(2018-11-30)
data.frame(
  y11 = sample(trans_tbl$answer, 100, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> dat

str(dat)
## 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  1 variable:
##  $ y11: chr  "Caribbean" "Chinese" "Indian" "Any other Black/African/Caribbean background, please describe" ...
```

Your data frame has more than one column but you didn't show it to us so I just made a single columns data frame with `y11`. Now, we just call `merge`:

```
dat <- merge(dat, trans_tbl, by.x="y11", by.y="answer", all.x=TRUE)

str(dat)
## 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ y11  : chr  "African" "African" "African" "African" ...
##  $ subst: chr  "Black" "Black" "Black" "Black" ...
```

And, then do some basic operations to turn the `subst` column into `y11` like your code does:

```
dat$y11 <- dat$subst
dat$subst <- NULL

str(dat)
## 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  1 variable:
##  $ y11: chr  "Black" "Black" "Black" "Black" ...
```

We can also use `dplyr` from the "tidyverse":

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2018-11-30)
data_frame( # this is the `data_frame()` function from dplyr, NOT `data.frame()` from base R
  y11 = sample(trans_tbl$answer, 100, replace = TRUE)
) -> dat

left_join(dat, trans_tbl, by = c("y11"="answer")) %>%
  select(y11 = subst)
## # A tibble: 100 x 1
##    y11         
##    <chr>       
##  1 Black       
##  2 Asian       
##  3 Asian       
##  4 Black       
##  5 Asian       
##  6 Mixed       
##  7 Arab & Other
##  8 Asian       
##  9 Arab & Other
## 10 Asian       
## # ... with 90 more rows
```

Another method is to use factor operations.

We'll use the same code to make a simulated data frame:

```
possible_answers <- c(
  "African", "Any other Asian background, please describe",
  "Any other Black/African/Caribbean background, please describe",
  "Any other ethnic group, please describ",
  "Any other Mixed/Multiple ethnic background, please describe",
  "Any other White background, please describe", "Arab", "Bangladeshi",
  "Caribbean", "Chinese", "English/Welsh/Scottish/Northern Irish/British",
  "Gypsy or Irish Traveller", "Indian", "Irish", "Pakistani", "White and Asian ",
  "White and Black African ", "White and Black Caribbean"
)

what_they_should_be <- c(
  "Black", "Asian", "Black", "Arab & Other", "Mixed", "White",
  "Arab & Other", "Asian", "Black", "Asian", "White", "White", "Asian",
  "White", "Asian", "Mixed", "Mixed", "Mixed"
)

set.seed(2018-11-30)
data.frame(
  y11 = sample(possible_answers, 100, replace = TRUE)
) -> dat
```

Note that I did *not* use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` for this one which makes it more like what you already have in your R session.

Now we can do:

```
dat$y11 <- as.character(factor(
  x = dat$y11,
  levels = possible_answers,
  labels = what_they_should_be
))

str(dat)
## 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  1 variable:
##  $ y11: chr  "Black" "Asian" "Asian" "Black" ...
```

And we get the translated values as a character vector and not as a factor.

Comment: The recoded variable is definitely a factor however.  The initial one you can make the case is more of a character variable.